# How to make responsive image in the table cell?

Tags: html, css

The image in the yellow `<div>` doesn't resize when the screen width gets smaller, and I don't know why. How can I fix that?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbyhrjxz/) and the code below.

```css
.s_container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  display: table;
}
.ssm_opcion {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: yellow;
}
.ssm_opcion img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#text_opcion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  background: green;
}
.ti-ab-d {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="s_container seleccion_simple_default">
  <div class="ssm_opcion">
    <img src="https://www.google.com.ar/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
  </div>
  <div id="text_opcion" class="ti-ab-d">Prueba</div>
</div>
```

Comment: width+table-layout. is this what you try to do : https://jsfiddle.net/hwr1dukq/1/

Comment: Yes, but I need that the width to be dynamic and adapt the real width of the image

Comment: actually, table(display or html) adapts to fit to content. you obviously try to do the exact opposite. like this maybe ? https://jsfiddle.net/hwr1dukq/2/

Comment: But then don't resize the images

Comment: the first one did, second not, then, what you'r asking for, is unclear to me or you did not understood how worked first one

Comment: In the first you've set width of image to 100% so it's gonna adapt to the parent's width 50%. Then if i have a 10x10 image it will be bigger and i don't want that

Comment: first resize image to width set to container, second expands container to image width's

Comment: Exactly, but i need the container expands to image's width like in the second and to resize like in the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that can be fixed with `table`, but you can use nested [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) to achieve the layout you want. See the demo and comments inline.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbtomcga/)**

```css
.s_container {
  display: flex; /*flex*/
}
.ssm_opcion {
  background: yellow;
}
.ssm_opcion img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#text_opcion {
  background: green;
  flex: 1 0 50px; /*grow + no shrink + basis*/
  display: flex; /*flex*/
  justify-content: flex-end; /*horizontal right*/
  align-items: flex-end; /*vertical bottom*/
}
```

```html
<div class="s_container seleccion_simple_default">
  <div class="ssm_opcion">
    <img src="https://www.google.com.ar/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
  </div>
  <div id="text_opcion" class="ti-ab-d">Prueba</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great!! You saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just set the normal image size parameters like this :

```
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
```